# Can a liquidity pool have more than 2 tokens

Tags: blockchain, liquid, solidity

The title sums it up I was watching a tutorial on how to deploy a liquidity pool using just solidity and wanted to know if it can have more than 2 tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquidity pools with more than two tokens are possible although they're not common as most major DEXs don't support them, off the top of my head the only places I can think of that support them are Curve and Balancer.

The typical two token liquidity pool, like those seen in Uniswap, functions on the idea that when adding liquidity you provide an equal value of each token, calculated with the formula:
x*y=k
So that the product of the quantities of the tokens is a constant, giving each token a weight of 50% in the equation. This is called the constant product market maker model.

Three or more token liquidity pools operate on the same concept but shift the weights around to accommodate the new tokens. So we could see something like:
x*y*z=k
But instead of each token being weighted for 50% as we saw for the two token model, we might have x be weighted for 20% whereas y and z are both weighted for 40%

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Uniswap, no, it does not have such a feature. But it might be possible mathematically. Still, I am not aware of an example of this.

Comment: Where could I read about mathematical possibilities of constant product market maker, with more than 2 tokens?

Comment: https://balancer.fi/ implemented such market maker.